# ContentDocumentLink Sharing

Tags: apex, contentdocument

I am trying to share a file that is uploaded to Parent record with a child record. So I assumed I could create a ContentDocumentLink handler to do this.  But the examples I have read reference the object where the file is originally uploaded to.  Is this required?  I want to be able to upload a file(to different objects) and copy it to a child record associated to the Parent. Do I have to know the object to be able to copy the  ContentDocumentLink to a child record? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes The trigger handler is required to share the file that has been uploaded on parent record with child records.

To know a contentDocumentLink is related to which record, You can query the **LinkedEntityId** field.

[Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) says, **LinkedEntityId** is ID of the linked object record. Can include Chatter users, groups, records (any that support Chatter feed tracking including custom objects), and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

Once you know the record and the object Type of the record, You can further share it with its child as per your requirement.